# Styling varies from iOS SDK 4.3 to 5.0

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, styling

I am using the built in Mail-composer in my App. Depending on which iOS SDK I am using to compile the App I get different results:

**GOOD**: iOS SDK 4.3
[good http://k.minus.com/jbmHVxSGOpPnhE.png](http://k.minus.com/jbmHVxSGOpPnhE.png)

---

**BAD**: iOS SDK 5.0
[bad http://k.minus.com/jwkNg6irPuMKU.png](http://k.minus.com/jwkNg6irPuMKU.png)

So what is the best way to achieve the same look using the SDK iOS 5.0?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Are you using a category to override drawRect in the navigation bar?

Comment: @jrturton: Yes I'm using a category for pre iOS 5.0 see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix my problem as follows. However, I am not sure if this is the cleanest possible solution so please let me know if there is a more standard or clean way to do it:

Since I need to support iOS > 4.0 I need the following two approaches.

For iOS < 5.0 (Using a Category)

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] doubleValue] < 5.0) {
        UIColor *color = kColorSCSNavigationBarBackgroundBlue;
        UIImage *img  = [UIImage imageNamed: @"TitleBar.png"];
        [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
        self.tintColor = color;
    }
}

@end
```

For iOS >= 5.0 (`applicationDidFinishLaunching` method in AppDelegate)

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] doubleValue] >= 5.0) {
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TitleBar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:kColorSCSNavigationBarBackgroundBlue];        
}
```